# Is this proof using well ordering principle correct? Are all parts necessary?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, well-orders

**Example.** Suppose the Royal Canadian Mint was to introduce a 3 cent coin like the British three pence to replace the 1 cent penny. Prove that 7 cents is now the largest quantity unable to be made with coins.

*Solution.* Since coins of value 10 cents and above can all be made with multiple nickels, we use only the 3 cent and 5 cent coins in our proof. Then, we are trying to prove
    \begin{equation*}
 \forall x \in \mathbb{N}, \exists y, z \in \mathbb{N}_0,\;\;(x > 7) \to (x=3y+5z).
 \end{equation*}
    Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there are amounts greater than 7 cents which cannot be paid with 3 cent and 5 cent coins. Let $S$ be the set containing all such amounts. Since $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and we have assumed $S \neq \emptyset$, by the Well-Ordering Principle, $S$ has a least element. Call it $n$. Now look at $n-3$. This cannot be paid with 3 cents and 5 cents either. Then, since $\min(S) = n$, we have $n-3 \leqslant 7 < n$. There are now three cases:

1. If $n-3=7$ then $n = 10 = 2 \times 5$
2. If $n-3=6$ then $n = 9 = 3 \times 3$
3. If $n-3=5$ then $n = 8 = 1 \times 3 + 1 \times 5$

Similarly, the amount $n-5$ cannot be paid with 3 cent and 5 cent coins either. Then we have $n-5 \leqslant 7 < n$ and the following five cases:

1. If $n-5 = 7$ then $n = 12 = 4 \times 3$
2. If $n-5=6$ then $n=11 = 2 \times 3 + 1 \times 5$
3. If $n-5=5$ then $n=10 = 2 \times 5$
4. If $n-5=4$ then $n=9 = 3 \times 3$
5. If $n-5=3$ then $n=8 = 1 \times 3 + 1 \times 5$

In all three cases we have a contradiction because we assumed $n$ cannot be made using 3 cent and 5 cent coins. So $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}, \exists y, z \in \mathbb{N}_0\;(x > 7) \to (x=3y+5z)$ and $S = \emptyset$. $\blacksquare$

---

I would like to know if, first of all, this proof is correct, and secondly, is it necessary to look at both $n-3$ and $n-5$ or just one or the other? This was used as an example in class but the professor used only $n-3$. Mustn't we consider $n \in \{ 11, 12 \}$ as well?

Comment: The argument doesn't require considering the cases of $n-5$. All is needed is move to a number not larger than $7$ by decreasing $n$ by one of the amounts of the two denominations.

Comment: How do you infer that $n - 3 \le 7$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) It looks correct to me. (2) It is not necessary to look at $n-5$. After you derive a contradiction, your proof-by-contradiction is done! There is no need to derive two contradictions; it doesn't double the amount of truth in the conclusion.

In particular, no, you don't have to consider the possibility that $n=11$, because you have already proved that the assumptions imply $n-3\leq 7$.